# Python-like enumerate and join

Tags: functional-programming, rust

I'm new to Rust and trying to convert some Python to Rust.  I have the following in Python:

```
>>> v = ((0, 0), (1,1), (2, 2))
>>> strings = "\n".join(("%s: (%s, %s)" % (i, val[0], val[1]) for i,val in enumerate(v))))
>>> print(strings)
0: (0, 0)
1: (1, 1)
2: (2, 2)
```

I'm trying to find the best/smartest/most rustic way of doing this:

```
let v = vec![(0, 0), (1,1), (2, 2)];

let strings = v
    .iter()
    .enumerate()
    .map(|(i, &(a,b))| format!("{:?}: ({}, {})", i, a, b))
    .collect::<Vec<_>>()
    .join("\n");

println!("{}", strings);
```

Answer (score 3):

Your code is reasonable, but there some small tweaks you could do.

1. Check out [itertools](https://github.com/bluss/rust-itertools), which adds some nice extensions to iterators. Specifically, it allows joining an iterator, instead of needing to collect to an intermediate `Vec`.
2. I'm unclear why you would use the `Debug` formatter for an integer.
3. Tuples have a space after the comma, between elements (see in the closure).
4. Your example might just be overly minimized, but there's no reason to use a `Vec` here, an array would suffice.

```
extern crate itertools;

use itertools::Itertools;

fn main() {
    let v = [(0, 0), (1, 1), (2, 2)];

    let strings = v.iter()
        .enumerate()
        .map(|(i, &(a, b))| format!("{}: ({}, {})", i, a, b))
        .join("\n");

    println!("{}", strings);
}
```

If you are OK changing the semantics a little, you can move the newline into the `format!` and `collect` into a `String`:

```
fn main() {
    let v = [(0, 0), (1, 1), (2, 2)];

    let strings: String = v.iter()
        .enumerate()
        .map(|(i, &(a, b))| format!("{}: ({}, {})\n", i, a, b))
        .collect();

    println!("{}", strings);
}
```

Note that there is now a trailing newline on the string.

The "unfortunate" thing about these solutions is that they all require intermediate string allocations - the result of `format!`.

There's a less-common method in itertools to deal with this: [`format_with`](https://docs.rs/itertools/0.5.4/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.format_with):

```
extern crate itertools;

use itertools::Itertools;

fn main() {
    let v = [(0, 0), (1, 1), (2, 2)];

    let formatter = v.iter()
        .enumerate()
        .format_with("\n", |(i, &(a, b)), fmt| {
            fmt(&format_args!("{}: ({}, {})", i, a, b))
        });

    let strings = format!("{}", formatter);

    println!("{}", strings);
}
```

I wouldn't worry about this until you know you need that extra bit of performance ^_^